# Changing image color

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, gradient

I have an image of a gradient. It's in a dull grey, and I would like to shift the enter thing to a bluer color without changing any of its other properties.

What's an easy way to do this?

I have both photoshop and gimp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Photoshop: The Hue/Saturation adjustment tool (shortcut Ctrl+U at least in PSCS3, accessible via Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation otherwise) has the "Colorize" option, which preserves the lightness of the color, but changes the hue and saturation values to any given color.

[image: Hue/Saturation box]

Answer (score 0):

The Colorize-Option should work for this pretty well.

Comment: What's the colorize option? Please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the point... :( ...I meant the Colorize-Option available in the GIMP Color-Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you didn't specifically ask for it in the question, I thought I'd post how to do this in [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) in case anyone is looking for it.

I was able to simulate Photoshop's Colorize feature by doing to following:

1. Open your image file
2. Add a new layer above the gradient
3. Set the Opacity of the new layer to something low like 30
4. Use the rectangle tool to draw a solid blue rectangle across the whole image

If it's too light or dark, you can adjust the transparency of the layer OR use a darker/lighter blue.